# Error when compile file custom.less to custom.css in Magento 2.1 [solved]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, less

I have file custom.less

```
.page-header {
  margin: auto;
}

.brand-logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

I use comment `php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme="TeeStyleUs/default"` to compile file custom.less

Expect file custom.css is:

```
.page-header {
  margin: auto;
}

.brand-logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Actual file custom.css is:

```
.page-header{margin: auto}
```

Something is wrong! Please help me!

**[SOLVED]**
Remove in `pub/static/frontend/<theme>` and `var/view_preprocessed/frontend/<theme>`.

Comment: I'm fixed! Remove in pub/static/frontend/<theme> and var/view_preprocessed/frontend/<theme>